Azure Machine Learning notebook doesn't change kernel
Even when new environments are created and all packages are installed and when i switch to new environment, it doesn't change the python version rather it uses 3.8.5 only.
But my environment is created with 3.10.11 and also when i do conda activate ai_env it shows python 3.10.11.
But Notebook doesn't use in compute instance.
When the environment is changed has to reflect the new environment with python assigned in my case has to be 3.10.11 and install new package in command line should reflect in the notebook.

By default the environment will be the kernel you select in notebook.

If you switch to different environment using conda activate in terminal still the environment will be same in notebook.

So, you switch in kernel tab as shown in first image and install required packages in that environment.

If you already have conda environment make it available in kernal list using below command in terminal.
ipython kernel install --user --name testenv --display-name "My Custom Name"

Refer this github documentation for more information.
